# Python PIL library - Saving an image from a RGBA array

Tags: python, save, png, python-imaging-library

I am currently using the PIL library to manipulate the pixel colours in an image.

My problem is that I don't know how to save a rgba array into a png file.

```
image = Image.open(filepath)
pixels = image.load()
```

...after changing the rgba values in pixels e.g.

```
pixels[2,10] = 30, 40, 50, 60
```

Then if I try to save pixels like this:

```
pixels.save(path)
```

i get error

```
AttributeError: 'PixelAccess' object has no attribute 'save'
```

How do I then save pixels back into an png file?

(sorry in advance if this is a stupid question)

Thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 8):

It's the Image object that has the `save` method, not the pixel access object.

```
image.save(path)
```

Modifying the pixel access object automatically causes the image to be modified too. So saving the image is effectively the same as saving the pixel access object.

Comment: So do you know how I can save the pixel access object back to png?

Comment: Modifying the pixel access object automatically causes the image to be modified too. So saving the image is effectively the same as saving the pixel access object.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. Also, you should edit that comment into the answer because that explanation is key in understanding this answer.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc, OK, fine by me.